# probleme to stock data in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, survey

i'm working on a survey generator. everythng is empty. the client enter one or many questions, and add one or many answers for each questions. These are send in my database.
i reach to code in js/jquery the dynamical generation of question and answers. my problem is that i don't know how to "link" answers to the question, in order to enter into my database question 1 answer1 answer2 answer3...question 2 answer1...
Is anybody can help me? i use also php to store my data and my database is mysql.

Comment: It sounds like I need a red magic button. Could you please provide more specifications? DB scheme? Where you need link in DB or in web app? Why do you need it, to send on server or to receive?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

The table structure should be something like this

**questions_master** table should be there to store all the questions and one column for every question whih is to store **right answe**r, then **answer_master** table should be there to store all the answers for given questions with question id like question id is 1 and there are 4 answers for question 1 then in answer table should be question id as 1 and option A as first answer option 2 as second answer and so on till option 4, then **user_answer** table should be there which should have question_id ans given answer with user id. this is basic structure as per my knowledge

Comment: Thanks to answer so fast. Actually my problem is not on the structure of my database, but how i can code my questions and answers to know that for the question 1, i have 3 choices whith id 1,3 and 4 for example.

Comment: can u please write your table structure so i can understand more about your requirement

Comment: i have tables :  formulary: idForm, nameForm.Then table question, with idQuestion, dateQuestion,nameQuestion,typeChoicer; then table choice : idChoice idQuestion, nameChoice, and then atable FormQuestion : id, idFormQuestion, idQuestion. I tried to put some code but it doesn't work..i'm at work, i 'll try maybe tonight if i can.  But my realm problem is that on a same page i can add many questions and many answers for these questions, so how  can i link the answer of questions 1 which are answer 1 and 3, and for the question 2 it is answer 2 and 4 fr example.